# How can I translate a method declared virtual in C # in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, porting

Is there a way to declare virtual methods and virtual properties inside an abstract class in Kotlin like in c #?

C# Example:

```
public abstract class myAbstractClass {

private string _myString = "";

        protected virtual string MyString
        {
            get { return _myString ; }
            set { _myString = value; }
        }


public virtual string getMyString(){
   return _myString
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code would be:

```kotlin
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected open var myString = "foo"
    open fun customGetString() = myString
}
```

This gives you a `myString` property that can be overriden by subclasses, and a `customGetString` function can can be overridden by subclasses. But if they don't override it, they get the default behaviour. Some examples:

```kotlin
class ConcreteClassA : MyAbstractClass()

class ConcreteClassB : MyAbstractClass() {
    override var myString = "bar"
}

class ConcreteClassC : MyAbstractClass() {
    override fun customGetString() = myString + "extra"
}

class ConcreteClassD : MyAbstractClass() {
    override var myString = "baz"
    override fun customGetString() = myString + "extra"
}

fun main() {
    println(ConcreteClassA().customGetString())
    println(ConcreteClassB().customGetString())
    println(ConcreteClassC().customGetString())
    println(ConcreteClassD().customGetString())
}
```

Output

```kotlin
foo
bar
fooextra
bazextra
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with C#, but if I understand the `virtual` and `protected` keywords correctly then it seems you want an overridable property that can be read from outside the class but can only be set from within the class or by a subclass. If that's the case then I believe the equivalent Kotlin code would be:

```kotlin
abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    open var myString = ""
        protected set
}
```

But if you really need the two properties and the function then the equivalent would be:

```kotlin
abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    private var _myString = ""
    protected open var myString by ::_myString

    open fun getMyStringAlt() = _myString
}
```

Unfortunately, at least on the JVM, the `getMyStringAlt()` function cannot be named `getMyString()` because it clashes with the getter for the `myString` property. I'm not sure if there's a workaround.

Comment: You can call `obj.myString` in the first example to get the value directly, which you can't in the C# version. But maybe that's what the OP was trying to do with the `getMyString()` method anyway? 

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of the method/function. I interpreted the C# code's intent as wanting to have an overridable property with a public getter and protected setter. But the approach by the OP seems brittle (the method and property can get out of sync). Perhaps there's a better approach for the C# code that the OP is not aware of (but like I said, I'm not familiar with C#). In any case, my first example is my translation of what I think the intent of the C# code is, and my second example is, as much as possible, a one-to-one translation.